# How to link permanently MKL libraries to Numpy in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, shared-libraries, intel-mkl

I built Numpy with the MKL libraries from Intel (a difficult process for me, it took my whole day!). Numpy needs to be linked to the MKL library with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, or at least this is the way I do it... So I use export in .bashrc to save the path and when I start a new console and run python, Numpy is correctly loaded with the libraries.

The problem is that it does not work with Eclipse which I use with Pydev to develop my programs. I still can add LD_LIBRARY_PATH somewhere in the preferences of Eclipse but the issue becomes real when I try to install Scipy. The installation script of Scipy needs to import Numpy and even when LD_LIBRARY_PATH is correctly set, I still have an error with the MKL libraries that cannot be imported:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 208, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 145, in setup_package
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libimf.so is one of the shared libraries of MKL that I have to link.
Apart from directly modifying the `__init__.py` file of Numpy (which I rather avoid because there may be a cleaner way to do that) I don't know what to do to permanently link Numpy to the MKL libraries.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have a read of the `ldconfig` man page.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is off topic... someone explains to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Talonmies I found the way to do that!
One must edit the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` and add the path to the libraries.
Here is how I did to find which path need to be added (it's very empirical...):

Whenever I get an error using Numpy related to a library that cannot be imported I look for to the path to this library this way:

`find /opt/intel -name library.so`

I get for example the path:
`/opt/intel/path/to/library.so`

I add this line to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf

# Manually added lines
/opt/intel/path/to/library.so
```

and then run `ldconfig` to 'link' the libraries!

Cheers! And thank you Talonmies!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when I added the directories instead of the shared object files itself to `ld.so.conf`.

Comment: Isn't it better to add a `.conf` file in `include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/`? Say `include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mylibs.conf` , so you avoid editing `include /etc/ld.so.conf`, which automatically detects all conf files in the directory.